# Client side validation issue when using a view model more than once on a page

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-validate, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a view model that has 4 properties in it, Username, Role, Application, and Reasons(Required). I am then using the following html helpers to show these in a view:

```
<form id="roleForm">
    <fieldset>
        <p>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RoleName)
            @Html.DisplayWithIdFor(model => model.RoleName)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.RoleName)
        </p>
        <p>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UsersName)
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.UsersName)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UsersName)
        </p>
        <p>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Application)
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Application)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Application)
        </p>
        <p>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Reasons)
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Reasons, new { @cols = "80", @rows = "4", @class = "k-textbox" })
            <span style="color:red;">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Reasons)</span>
        </p>
        <button class="button-yes k-button" type="button">OK</button>
        <button class="button-no k-button" type="button">Cancel</button>
        <!-- Allow form submission with keyboard without duplicating the dialog button -->
        <input type="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

However due to the nature of a particular system on one page I have 3 different things that I need to use this view model for on a single page. To do this I have 3 partial views and 3 Kendo UI windows, Again this part is working.

The issue then arises that JQuery always pics up the first Text Area defined on the page, this is expected as they all have the same ID's so I have looked to change the ID's on the other 2 Text Areas, see bellow:

@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Reasons, new { @id = "AddCompanyReasons", @cols = "80", @rows = "4", @class = "k-textbox" })

This now finds the correct text Area. However now the issue is the validation is always returning true on the client side despite getting the text or lack of text from the text box.

```
var isReasonValid = $('#AddCompanyReasons').valid();
```

I had thought that maybe creating an attribute to change the property name slightly every time the property appears on the page might solve this but it seems a bit extreme.

Has anyone come across this problem before and does any one have any ideas on how to solve this?

**EDIT**

Terleric Kendo Window Popups to show the three forms:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Window()
    .Name("remove-role-window")
    .Title("Update Roles")
    .Visible(false)
    .Content(@<text>
        @Html.Partial("~/Areas/UserCurrentRoles/Views/UserCurrentRoles/_AXRemoveRole.cshtml")
    </text>)
    .Modal(true)
    .Width(500)
    .Events(e => e.Open("resetDialog"))
)

@(Html.Kendo().Window()
    .Name("remove-company-window")
    .Title("Update Roles")
    .Visible(false)
    .Content(@<text>
        @Html.Partial("~/Areas/UserCurrentRoles/Views/UserCurrentRoles/_RemoveAXCompany.cshtml")
    </text>)
    .Modal(true)
    .Width(500)
    .Events(e => e.Open("resetCompanyDialog"))
  )

@(Html.Kendo().Window()
    .Name("add-company-window")
    .Title("Update Roles")
    .Visible(false)
    .Content(@<text>
         @Html.Partial("~/Areas/UserCurrentRoles/Views/UserCurrentRoles/_AddAXCompany.cshtml", Model)
    </text>)
    .Modal(true)
    .Width(500)
    .Events(e => e.Open("resetAddDialog"))
)
```

Answer (score -1):

validation works on document ready. after document ready if html is dynamically changing. by any operation means any element has been reprinted or recreated will not be validated. you will have to run validation function again to validate all fields.

Comment: I am running the validation code in an event handler and the code works fine in the first kendo window just not in the other two. Could the jqyery `.valid` function is looking for the a property with the new ID value which doesn't actually exist?

Comment: how are other two pages printed. page getting refresh or partialview is rendering

Comment: They are all on the same page though the forms are in separate partial views and called by the kendo windows that I have added to the question.

Comment: Answer is half-correct. However, if HTML is dynamically changed, you can not *"run validation function again"*. The initialization method is simply ignored if it's called more than once. The plugin developer gives you the `.rules()` method for adding/removing rules dynamically... but the other options cannot be changed.